# Authenticate using SAML and Okta from MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I need to replace windows auth in an intranet site with SAML against Okta.

I'm having very little luck finding an example that does not require a PhD to understand.  Can anyone point me to a dummies guide or some samples for this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try the Mvc4MusicStore sample to use Okta instead of AD:
https://github.com/okta/okta-music-store

You need to modify your code to use the Okta Membership and Role providers.